# How do I use homebrew to uninstall Python 2.7.10? Python 3.7 also installed. Cannot install/work with virtualenv or Flask

Tags: python-2.7, homebrew, python-3.7

I need to uninstall Python 2.7.10 completely off my system so that I can install and work with virtualenv and Flask. I also have Python 3.7 installed and want to keep working with that. I'm working with Mac 10.14.2.

Using the terminal. Command [python --version] shows 2.7.10. However, when I did [brew install Python3], it shows me that it is already installed and up-to-date. If possible, I'd like to reset even (uninstalling all Python on my computer) and reinstalling python 3.7. (the version is 3.7.2_1)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 comes preinstalled with macOS, so I'm not sure if it is a good idea to uninstall it. You can use the command `python3` to use the version 3.7 you installed with homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your global python version to be fixed (3.7 or others), you can check out [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

If you want to use different python versions for different projects, you can check out [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)

Don't bother uninstalling what came with the system. (to be safe?)